# Updating the time filter on a filterbox will not update the dropdowns filters data

Tags: apache-superset

I was wondering if this is a bug or it is the expected behavior:

When I update the time filter to a different time range on a filterbox in a dashboard, it will not update the dropdowns filter data. I would have expected it will adjust the dropdowns options to reflect the options matching the relevant time frame, but it doesn't. Is that a bug or is it by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes what you're looking for is a contextual filter. Remove irrelevant data from filters according to you date time.

To do this you will have to do multiple slice. One chart / filter based you same data sources. It's working well on my side.

To this is where I get the solution to my issue : https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/9003